# matplotlib fill under LOWESS curve

Tags: matplotlib

I have a plot for which I'd like to fill the area under the LOWESS line used to smooth a histogram. In `matplotlib` I believe that `plt.fill_between()` should be the way to go, but for some reason the sample code I have isn't doing what I was expecting; it's filling some bits but those are staggered and do not start from `y=0`. Any ideas on how to make this work?

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.loadtxt('numbers.tt')
a = a[~np.isnan(a)]
a[:20]
# array([ 0.04184204,  0.07509347, -0.00443857, -0.03590184, -0.0294351 ,
#       -0.02969616, -0.02780433, -0.02362442, -0.04242367, -0.01171937,
#       -0.0208392 , -0.02976209, -0.03771409, -0.0261862 , -0.04404418,
#        0.00259364, -0.01267109, -0.01128568, -0.00380218, -0.03742523])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y, bins, _ = ax.hist(a, bins=100, color='w')
x = 0.5 * (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])
lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y, x, frac=0.1)
_ = ax.plot(lowess[:, 0], lowess[:, 1])  # draw line
_ = ax.fill_between(lowess[:, 0], 0, lowess[:, 1])  # draw fill from y=0 to y value in lowess
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like your bars have a higher (or is it lower?) Z-order than the filled curve. I'd remove the change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `y, bins, _ = ax.hist(a, bins=100, color='w')
x` actually draws your histogram, in white, on the plot. Histograms are bar charts, which are made out of rectangular patches. These patches have a higher precedence than the fill of the curve, which is drawn behind the patches. Notice that the line plot of the curve itself cuts off the bars, because it actually has a higher precedence.

You can visualize what I'm saying better by changing the color of the histogram from `'w'` to `'r'`, or similar. However, it sounds like you don't want to draw the histogram at all. In that case, use [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) instead of [`matplotlib.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html). The numpy function is what matplotlib uses to generate the data under the hood anyway:

```
y, bins = np.histogram(a, bins=100)
```

Comment: Ah, good catch. I did actually find that setting `visible=False` in the call to `ax.hist()`would solve this, but indeed I don't even need to draw the histogram, and since I'm already using `Numpy` your solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need/want to import `Numpy` and use the arrays from `ax.hist` directly, then setting `visible=False` in the call to `ax.hist()` should solve this issue:

```
y, bins, _ = ax.hist(a, bins=100, color='w', visible=False)
x = 0.5 * (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])
lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y, x, frac=0.1)
_ = ax.plot(lowess[:, 0], lowess[:, 1])  # draw line
p = ax.fill_between(lowess[:, 0], 0, lowess[:, 1])
```

[image]